# Why does PC still get a little power from power socket turned off through remote control?

Tags: power-supply, remote-control

I have bought a power supply device to remote-control the power consumption at home. This works very well, however the PC has a little blue power light that keeps blinking from time to time even though the power socket is turned off. You can not turn the PC on or similar, but it still seems to get some power from the supply for the light to blink. This of course does not happen anymore when I completely remove the power plug.

How can this be and is this normal for remote-controllable power supply devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote control switch — I assume it is controlled via powerline communications, like X10 — requires a small amount of "leakage" current through the load at all times in order to operate its internal circuitry and to communicate.

This leakage current is sufficient to allow a charge to accumulate in your PC's power supply and blink the LED occasionally. The same thing occurs with some LED and CFL lamps used with such a switch.

One quick way to mitigate the problem is to plug a low-power incandescant lamp in parallel with the PC. This will provide a path for the leakage current that prevents the voltage that the PC sees from getting too high.